# Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name. PasswordChangeView and PasswordChangeForm

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin, django-class-based-views

I am trying to implement a functionality of changing the password of the current user in Django . But no matter what I use, I always get this `everse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name` error and a Template showing these lines of codes.

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/squad-minds/PycharmProjects/squad-services/Admin_interface/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 3



1   {% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
2   {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
3   <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
4   <head>
```

where  `}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI` is in Red Colour. I have implemented this using the CBV

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class PasswordChange(UserPassesTestMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

`path('password/change', views.PasswordChange.as_view(), name='change_password'),`

What is this Index thing and why am I getting this?

Comment: can you post html template code and urls.py? Try searching 'index' keyword in you  password change and base.html template and check if there's anything like {% url 'index' %}

Comment: Some of the admin base page is using that index url.
Search for  {% url 'index' %}